# Why jquery.animate on a textarea make the blinking cursor disapears?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, textarea, cursor

I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTextArea").focus(function() {
        $("#myTextArea").animate({ "height": "75px"}, "normal");
        return false;
    });
```

to expand a textbox when it gets focus. The expand occurs, however the blinking cursor disapears, at least in Firefox!

Edited: The textarea is still focused, and i can type on it.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to show it again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return false` statement is cancelling the `focus` action :)  You only get a cursor when the element is focused, I'd just remove this line from your function.

Aside from that, `.focus()` in a text area isn't something you can reclaim easily, because it had a position that matters, you're better off sticking with a CSS change here:

```
$("#myTextArea").focus(function() {
    $(this).css({ "height": "75px" });
});
```

This won't affect cursor behavior at all and work the saema cross browsers (`focus` is still different amongst browsers), but of course won't animate.  The alternative (I haven't tested this in all browsers) is that you could trigger the focus again with the same args after the animate, restoring the position, like this:

```
$("#myTextArea").focus(function(e) {
    if($(this).height() == 75) return;
    $(this).animate({ height: 75}, "normal", function() {
        $(this).blur().trigger(e);
    });
});​
```

[You can test this from here](http://jsfiddle.net/7FSd4/), just be sure to check all browsers, as `focus` behavior can vary slightly between them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However i think the textarea is focused, because i can type on it, and the cursor never appears.
I will try these solutions and post some feedback after :)

Comment: For some reason it is the css of the container div that is disabling the cursor... And i cant manage to make it work... So ill use your first sugestion for now. Althoug this isnt the better solution, if no one answers a better one i will accept it. Thanks for the help!